# A type from both keys and values of other type

Tags: typescript

I have a particular type:

```js
type TypeOne = {
  option1: string;
  option2: boolean;
};
```

On the basis of that type, I would like to achieve something like this:

```js
type TypeTwo = {
  field: 'option1';
  fieldValue: string;
} | {
  field: 'option2';
  fieldValue: boolean;
}
```

How to do this more dynamically, without bigger code boilerplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) can help here:

```
type Fields<T, Key = keyof T> = Key extends keyof T ? { field: Key, fieldValue: T[Key] } : never;

type TypeTwo = Fields<TypeOne>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkB20C8UDeAoKUD2YwAlnkgIwBcUAzsAE5FIDmA3DvoSUgExUBGePABsIAQyRsAvmyyhIUAGJEIQgCbUAPDAA0UANIQQUdAGtDeAGawAfMf2GoEAB7AISdVDMhLsKAH5MKAtlNSoDEF1glVUANVEhAFcIKhgAbXCAXShJKCoUADcIOhk5aDhIGAB3PDslaM1yxBRrIA)

We produce field/fieldValue for each key in provided type.